# Transparent NavBar with persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, persistent, tabview

I am using `persistent_bottom_nav_bar` package:

https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

which does exactly what I want, except it is missing an important `Scaffold` function:

```
extendBody: true
```

The package tells me the following:

> NOTE: This widget includes SCAFFOLD (based on CupertinoTabScaffold),
> so no need to declare it.

I am looking for a solution to be able have `extendedBody: true` while using this package

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is modify the package, and add this property to the built-in scaffold.

1- Go to the package directory, example:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\PackageFolderName
```

2- Copy the Package to your project (the whole PackageFolderName, and paste at same level with `pubspec.yaml` )

3- Modify the Package's code, i.e. find the Scaffold and add the property

4- Modify your Project's `pubspec.yaml` and change the path of the package to

```
Package Name: 
  path: ./PackageFolderName/
```

5- Save your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: although this is a reasonable approach, the package itself does not seems to inhered from `Scaffold` thus I can not simply add this. I guess I am looking for someone who managed a work-around himself